# Perl ) Enter and exit each sub directories

Tags: perl

I have a question about Perl.

I have to make a loop.

A is main directory. And it has sub directories A001,A002,...,Axxx. Note that the end number is not defined. It depends on.

I have to do the same works in each sub directories.
So start from the main directory A. Go to A001 directory and work something , get back to main directory, and go to A002, and work something ... repeat.

I made code about what I have to do in each sub directories, **but I don't know how to enter and exit each sub directories**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you said _I made code about what I have to do in each sub directories..._ could you please show us the code.

Comment: Sounds like you might be able to use `File::Find` or the non-core `File::Find::Rule`.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has a [`chdir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir) function. That's probably what you want.